# Refresh primaary tab in SF service console

Tags: javascript, console

I am following this [blog](http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.ca/2015/07/how-to-refresh-record-in-console.html) to refresh primary tab based on certain event in sub tab. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function RefreshPrimaryTab() 
    {
        sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(showTabId);
    }

    var showTabId = function showTabId(result) 
    {
        var tabId = result.id;
        alert('Primary Tab IDs: primaryTabId ' + tabId );
        sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId , true, refreshSuccess);
    };

    var refreshSuccess = function refreshSuccess(result) 
    {
        //Report whether refreshing the primary tab was successful
        if (result.success == true) 
        {
            alert('Primary tab refreshed successfully');
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert('Primary did not refresh');
        }
    };

</script>
```

Everything is working great but only with the prescence of alert message in `function showTabId`. If I remove the alert message, primary tab is not getting refreshed. Looking for any inputs if anyone experience similar issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any of you facing the same issue, use settimeout as below:

```
 function RefreshPrimaryTab() 
    {
setTimeout( function() { sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(showTabId); }, 1000);

    }
```

you dont require alert when used above :)